# Autenticação em diferentes bancos de dados

Tags: java, web-service, autenticação, banco-de-dados

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um webservice (em java) de integração em diferentes bases de dados e acabei caindo num problema no qual não estou encontrando solução. As queries são introduzidas manualmente e serão chamadas de acordo com o serviço cadastrado. Os acessos a base a ser integrada serão informados durante o cadastro no banco no sistema, como usuário, nome da base, senha..

Em alguns momentos, irei precisar autenticar um usuário do sistema, mas alguns sistemas cadastram a senha com criptografia MD5, SHA1, ou suas próprias criptografias.

Uma forma de autenticar um usuário seria:

```
select * from users where username = 'user' and password = 'password'
```

O problema é como passar a senha criptografada.

A minha abordagem está correta? Ou há alguma forma mais fácil de fazer isso.

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Você tem acesso as criptografias utilizadas nos outros softwares? Pois é basicamente isso, você teria que criptografar e comparar com o que está no banco de dados.

Comment: Sim, possuo acesso as outras criptografias. Me parece que vai ser bem hardcode.

Comment: Recentemente passei por algo parecido, aparentemente basta você fazer a criptografia com o que o usuário informar na tela e comparar com o que está no banco.

Comment: Sua abordagem está incorreta, pelo menos do meu ponto de vista. Usar base de dados para integrar aplicações expõe algo que deveria estar encapsulado. Uma aplicação deve ser dona do banco de dados e qualquer acesso, principalmente no que se refere ao controle de acesso, deve ser feito através de uma API, caso contrário você vai ter que duplicar regras de segurança e minha experiência diz que isso tem 99% de probabilidade de dar errado. Pode ser chato, mas o ideal seria que cada aplicação tivesse seu próprio web service e então você faz o seu web service de integração em cima disso.

Comment: @utluiz, então o protocolo SOAP também estaria incorreto, levando em conta a segurança?

Comment: @RicardoFarias SOAP é um protocolo de transferência de objetos. Você deve estar falando de SOA. Nunca ouvi falar de que é necessário ou recomendável em SOA que várias aplicações usem a mesma base. Geralmente você usa um middleware para comunicação onde as várias aplicações se conversam via mensagens, por exemplo usando JMS.

Comment: E se houverem muitas aplicações, você pode usar um ESB (*enterprise service bus*) para roteamento das mensagens entre as diversas aplicações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A minha abordagem está correta?

*Provavelmente não*.

Segurança não se resume a comparar senha no banco de dados (autenticação).

Um ponto tão importante envolve o nível de acesso dos usuários (autorização), onde cada sistema geralmente tem suas regras.

Eu diria que autenticar o usuário numa nova aplicação sem levar em conta as regras de segurança e as regras de negócio das aplicações já existentes é uma violação direta de segurança.

A abordagem tradicional para implementar integração, seja usando SOA ou qualquer outro modelo de integração, é delegar as chamadas para os sistemas existentes de forma que eles executem as regras de negócio apropriadas e retornem os valores corretos.

Como fazer isso na prática é outra história.

Uma forma é usar Web Services, onde cada aplicação disponibiliza os *endpoints* necessários e a aplicação principal os aciona de acordo com as informações que ela precisa obter. Web Services podem ser implementados com protocolo SOAP ou de forma mais leve com REST.
2.

Outra forma, se as aplicações são modulares, é incluir módulos (JARs, por exemplo) das outras aplicações dentro da sua aplicação de integração e então executar diretamente os métodos das APIs. A desvantagem é que sua aplicação precisa incluir todas as outras dentro dela e atualizar as versões conforme necessário, além de prover a configuração necessária para as outras aplicações executarem. Parece complicado, mas já vi isso funcionar na prática, embora não considere o ideal.

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, cada aplicação possui um método de autenticação próprio, isto é, cada uma armazena do seu jeito as informações do usuário. Acredito que o primeiro passo, mais importante e mais penoso, é centralizar essas informações de forma que todas as aplicações façam uso de um módulo comum de cadastro de usuários.

Cada aplicação ainda pode executar a autorização de forma independente, mas sem um cadastro unificado para autenticação você vai ter muitas dores de cabeça quando usuários tentarem acessar recursos de aplicações diferentes. O primeiro problema (e mais comum) é a sincronia das informações do cadastro.